# Loop parallelism in java

Tags: java, parallel-processing

Can anyone let me know how to parallelize for loops using Java 5's ***JParallelLoops.jar***?

Comment: Where's this jar from? Why you don't just use a thread?

Comment: [JParallelLoops on sourceforge](http://jparallelloops.sourceforge.net/) - this is not part of the Java SDK.

Comment: Why don't you guys use a real username?

Comment: BTW: I was `Java 5.0` rather than `Java 5` ;)

Comment: ok in that case, how to parallelize, other than the thread pool executor way?

Comment: Why don't you want to use the "thread pool executor way"? Note that parallelizing applications is most often not a trivial task and might require some sensible redesign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JParallelLoops looks like a 3rd party library (http://sourceforge.net/projects/jparallelloops/). From a quick glance at their source code it seems like they have quite some JavaDocs so you might want to start there.

Besides that, just parallelizing loops might not provide the performance gain you'd expect. Maybe you can redesign your code to use thread pools (e.g. using `ThreadPoolExecutor`, `FutureTask` etc.).